# Are lax functor categories into a cartesian closed 2-category cartesian closed?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, cartesian-closed-categories

Suppose that $C$ is a complete closed monoidal category and $I$ is any small category. Then the functor category $Fun(I,C)$ is again a closed monoidal category with the pointwise tensor product $F \otimes G (x) = F(x) \otimes G(x)$. [See here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed+monoidal+category)

I am wondering about an analog of this for strict 2-categories. I just care about the cartesian setting. So, specifically let $C$ be a complete strict 2-category whose underlying 1-category is cartesian closed. Let $I$ be a small strict 2-category (though I just care about the case that $I = (0 \to 1)$ is the arrow 1-category). Let $Lax(I,C)$ denote the [lax functor 2-category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/generalized+Gray+tensor+product) of strict functors, lax natural transformations, and modifications.

Is it the case that the underlying category of $Lax(I,C)$ is Cartesian closed?

Comment: Consider the case when the underlying category of $C$ is trivial, so 2-endomorphisms of the identity form a commutative monoid. Then the underlying category of $\mathrm{Lax}(0\to1,C)$ will have single object with that endomorphism monoid, and it hardly ever has binary products.

Comment: So the monoidal structure on C must be compatible with the 2-category structure on C. go ahead and assume that.

Comment: Well in certain sense it is in that example. Could you add what kind of compatibility do you mean?

Comment: For simplicity we might suppose that C has strict 2-products, and that this gives the monoidal structure. Your example doesn't have that unless C is trivial.

Comment: On the otherhand your example does give a monoidal 2-category, just not cartesian monoidal. In that case the lax functor category does indeed happen to be monoidal, just not Cartesian monoidal, as expected.

Comment: For your purposes, it would suffice to construct a small 2-category $I'$ such that $Strict(I',C) \cong Lax(I,C)$. Probably an Australian could quote you a general result that does this, but if you just need $I$ to be the arrow category, you can probably do it by hand -- after all, when $I$ is the point, then $I'$ would be the walking monad $\mathbf{B}\Delta_+$.

Comment: @TimCampion That is a good idea, but I am not quite sure how it solves my problem. It is somehow important in my case that the objects of $Lax(I, C)$ are the strict functors (not lax), but that the morphisms are lax transformations. (This funny hybrid is the thing which is adjoint to the Gray tensor product, if that helps).

Comment: Ah, yes, I too misread the question

Answer (score 1):

At the generality of closed monoidal categories, I think I have a counterexample that will go into my paper with Claudia Scheimbauer --- I need to go over it one more time, so let me not do it here.

But you care most about the Cartesian case.  Let $\mathcal C$ be a strict 2-category, by which I mean a 1-category enriched in $\mathrm{Cat}$, the 1-category of categories.  For objects $X,Y \in \mathcal C$, I will write $\mathcal C(X,Y) \in \mathrm{Cat}$ for the enriched hom, and $\mathcal C_0(X,Y) \in \mathrm{Set}$ for the uninriched hom.  It is worth distinguishing two notions of "Cartesian".  Let's say that an *enriched product* of $X$ and $Y$ is an object $X \times Y$ and a natural-in-$A$ isomorphism of categories $\mathcal C(A,X\times Y) \cong \mathcal C(A,X) \times \mathcal C(A,Y)$, and an *unenriched product* is an object $X \times_0 Y$ and a natural-in-$A$ isomorphism of SETS $\mathcal C_0(A,X\times_0 Y) \cong \mathcal C_0(A,X) \times \mathcal C_0(A,Y)$.  Then any enriched product is also unenriched, but the converse I think can fail.  (If, say, $\mathcal C$ is tensored over finite categories, then unenriched products are also enriched products.)  So I will assume you mean that $\mathcal C$ has enriched products.

Let $X \overset x \to X'$ and $Y \overset y \to Y'$ be objects of the lax arrow category, since you only care about the case $I = (\bullet \to \bullet)$.  I want to prove that their product is $(X \times Y) \overset{x\times y}\to (X' \times Y')$.  Let's test this by mapping in with some other object $A \overset a \to A'$.  Such a map consists of:

- A map $(f,g) : A \to (X \times Y)$.  There are $\mathcal C(A,X\times Y) = \mathcal C(A,X) \times \mathcal C(A,Y)$ of these.
- A map $(f',g'): A' \to (X' \times Y')$.  There are $\mathcal C(A',X' \times Y') = \mathcal C(A',X') \times \mathcal C(A',Y')$ of these.
- A 1-morphism in $\mathcal C(A,X' \times Y') = \mathcal C(A,X') \times \mathcal C(A,Y')$ between certain compositions of the above data with $a,x,y$.

Now, I think that naturality and functoriality of $\mathcal C, \times$ tell you that the 1-morphism you need, after writing everything as a product, is something with source $(f'a,g'a)$ and target $(xf,yg)$, which is exactly what you need it to be.

So I think in this case the answer is Yes, the lax functor category has products, and they are computed pointwise.

Comment: Well, I misread, and didn't see you wanted cartesian closed categories, rather than just cartesian categories.  But I think via a "functor of points" approach the same coordinate-full calculation works.

Comment: Yes, the point is whether or not there are inner homs.